# Trouble getting a CSS vertical linear background gradient to display properly in all major browsers

Tags: css, gradient, cross-browser

I got it to display exactly how I want it in Firefox, but with every other browser there seems to be some problems. This website isn't exactly public (as in, no one knows of it) yet as I'm still trying to get things to display properly, but the URL is: http://www.mixbin.net (just view:source for the code - there's nothing server side interfering)

**Firefox:** Perfect.
**Chrome:** Perfect except the bottom margin is being ignored in the .content class.
**Opera:** Perfect except the bottom margin is being ignored in the .content class.
**Safari:** Displays gradient properly but forces a refresh as soon as you scroll halfway down the page.
**Internet Explorer:** Displays gradient properly but .content div is cut off where the gradient stops.

```css
background:linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #353535 100%); /*W3C*/
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #353535 100%); /*FF3.6+*/
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #353535 100%); /*IE10+*/
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #353535 100%); /*Opera 11.10+*/
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #000000), color-stop(100%, #353535)); /*Chrome,Safari4+*/
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #353535 100%); /*Chrome10+,Safari5.1+*/
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#353535',GradientType=0 ); /*IE6-9*/
```

No images wanted. So please don't reply with, "just make a background image".

**Update 2:** Everything (including IE), is now working. I switched these two lines from:

```css
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#000000 0,#353535 100%);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,#000),color-stop(100%,#353535));
```

To:

```css
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #353535);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000000), to(#353535));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CSS for the gradient is:

```
background: linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #353535 512px);
```

there will be no need for a `<div>` with height 512px. Unfortunately, this solution works for every browser except IE.

Back to your extra background `<div>` approach. I copied and modified your code a little. This works for all browsers.

```css
body {
  background: #353535;
}
.content {
  background-color: white;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
#background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 512px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #353535 100%); /*W3C*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #353535 100%); /*FF3.6+*/
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #353535 100%); /*IE10+*/
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #353535 100%); /*Opera 11.10+*/
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #000000), color-stop(100%, #353535)); /*Chrome,Safari4+*/
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #353535 100%); /*Chrome10+,Safari5.1+*/
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#353535', GradientType=0); /*IE6-9*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="background"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You could also use css3 pie for gradients in Internet Explorer: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Whoa... Thanks for the PIE tip!

Comment: omg thanks so much man. This works perfectly! I just omitted the IE one and IE users will have to deal with it. Thanks again. It has been updated based on your code.

Comment: Edit: I forgot to modify code for the first solution. Did you know that you can use pixels instead of percentage for the color stops? (It does not matter now, as you picked the second solution. Just thought I'd let you know.)

Comment: @JimmyX Switching everything to 512px and removing the "height:512px" actually didn't work for some reason so I just left it in. But Safari is still crashing :[

Comment: @tactzer0 Then you can check out the second solution in the jsfiddle, which keeps the div of height 512px.

Comment: @JimmyX I believe that's the solution I'm currently using (feel free to check my source), but Safari is still crashing.

Comment: Update: While viewing http://css3please.com, I realized they omitted the 100% value. I tried it and now it works! I updated the original post to reflect what made it work.

Answer (score -1):

This might not be the solution you are looking for but, since you will have to use hacks to make it looks the same on different browsers, why wont you use an image of the gradient and repeat it in the background.

If your background gradient is 300px, make the image with 300px height and 1px width (image size wont be over 1KB), and repeat it in your background

`background: url('bg_gradient.jpg') repeat-x 0px 0px;`

It will work on all the browsers without any hassle;

Comment: Thanks for viewing, but I'm already well aware of that. I'm trying to eliminate http requests not create them.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant that was added after I added this post mate :)